# Complex aggregate query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create temp table tokens (
    id serial not null,
    name text not null,
    locale text not null,
    CONSTRAINT tokens_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
insert into tokens(name, locale) values 
('e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4', 'en_US'),
('e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4', 'en_US'),
('e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4', 'en_US'),
('e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4', 'en_US'),
('e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4', 'en_US'),
('e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4', 'en_GB'),
('e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4', 'en_AU'),
('8156773b9da51b7cffb4a1af1a326464', 'de_DE'),
('8156773b9da51b7cffb4a1af1a326464', 'de_DE'),
('8156773b9da51b7cffb4a1af1a326464', 'de_DE'),
('8156773b9da51b7cffb4a1af1a326464', 'de_AT')

select 
    max(cnt) max, name, locale
from (
    select count(id) cnt, name, locale
    from tokens
    group by name, 
    locale
) q
group by
    name, 
    locale
order by 
    max(cnt) desc, 
    name, 
    locale

/*
Result:
max;name;locale
5;e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4;en_US
3;8156773b9da51b7cffb4a1af1a326464;de_DE
1;8156773b9da51b7cffb4a1af1a326464;de_AT
1;e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4;en_AU
1;e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4;en_GB

Expected result:
max;name;locale
5;e47dd0440c923a77915791ffab7346f4;en_US
3;8156773b9da51b7cffb4a1af1a326464;de_DE
*/
```

I need token and locale with maximum count, but problem is if I group by locale i get wrong result

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7adda/3)

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was wrong. FuzzyTree's is the one i would have given, but there is no point in having the same answer more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select cnt, name, locale from (
    select 
        cnt, name, locale,
        row_number() over (partition by name order by cnt desc) rn
    from (
        select count(id) cnt, name, locale
        from tokens
        group by name, 
        locale
    ) t1
) q where rn = 1 order by cnt desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/33b36/5

Comment: +1 I failed to understand the exact question, though i have answered this kind of questions a million times. Boy, i even wish i got a penny for every such question i have answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one row, use `LIMIT`:

```
    select count(id) cnt, name, locale
    from tokens
    group by name, locale
    order by count(id) desc
    LIMIT 1
```